# Angular 2 MVW - MVC, MVA, MVP, MVVM?

Tags: angular, model-view-controller, mvvm, mvw

Angular 1 (AngularJS) was called an MVW-Framework. MVW stands for Model-View-Whatever. Is Angular 2 still MVW?

Is MVW the same as MV*?

I know that Whatever means that it could be a ViewModel or a Controller. Model and View is still the same.

But can MVW also mean that there is a Presenter or an Adapter?

> I know that the Model can be factories or services, the controller is the component class and the view is the component template (template or templateUrl), if I use the MVC pattern. The Service can be used via Dependecy Injections in the class constructor of my component file.
>   The member variables can be set there. The view binds the member variables.

I am not sure, but the ViewModel is also the component class. But I don't understand the difference in Angular 2, because I couldn't find any examples for MVC or MVVM.

1. At first I want to know if Angular 2 is also MVW?
2. Then is MVW the same as MV*?
3. After that is there a person who know a good example which shows the code difference between MVC and MVVM.
4. If Angular 2 also support Presenter or Adapter, are there any good code examples for this two pattern?

I think the theory behind these concepts I have understood really well, but I can't find code examples or clear answers how you can use these patterns. Also I can'f find a clear answer If Adapter and Presenter is also supported by Angular 2.

These links can help:
[Angular2: MVC, MVVM or MV*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36950582/angular2-mvc-mvvm-or-mv)

[How MVC pattern can be explained in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38844771/how-mvc-pattern-can-be-explained-in-angular-2)

But it's all theory and no practice.

In the documentation (angular.io) I only can found these two statements:

> The Angular application manages what the user sees and can do, achieving this through the interaction of a component class instance (the component) and its user-facing template.
>
> You may be familiar with the component/template duality from your experience with model-view-controller (MVC) or model-view-viewmodel (MVVM). In Angular, the component plays the part of the controller/viewmodel, and the template represents the view.

or this

> An Angular class responsible for exposing data to a view and handling most of the view’s display and user-interaction logic.
>
> The component is one of the most important building blocks in the Angular system. It is, in fact, an Angular directive with a companion template.
>
> Apply the @Component decorator to the component class, thereby attaching to the class the essential component metadata that Angular needs to create a component instance and render the component with its template as a view.
>
> Those familiar with "MVC" and "MVVM" patterns will recognize the component in the role of "controller" or "view model".

I am really confused about this topic. I hope there is a person who can help me.

On this link there is a similar question to MVW. Is the shown example a vaild example for MVC?
[What does MVW stand for in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801814/what-does-mvw-stand-for-in-angular2)